# Reading Attached Image directly form memory using Autocad .Net API

Tags: .net, bitmap, autocad, intptr

I have a large JPEG image (10000*11000px), attached to an Autocad drawing, that I want to crop multiple times. I cannot load it into memory using .Net, I get an out of memory exception. the only thing I think I can do is read it directly from Autocad. To do that, there is a method of the "RasterImageDef" class called "OpenImage" witch returns an IntPtr to the image. I tried to create a Bitmap object from the IntPtr and the save it to disk. I get no errors but the saved image is black. here' the code :

```
public static void IntPtrTest()
{
        Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Database db = doc.Database;
        Editor ed = doc.Editor;

        ObjectId imageDict = RasterImageDef.GetImageDictionary(db);

        if (imageDict == ObjectId.Null)
        {
            ed.WriteMessage("No images in the drawing.\n");
            return null;
        }

        using (DocumentLock dlock = doc.LockDocument())
            {
                using (Transaction Tx = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
                {
                    DBDictionary ImageDic =
                      (DBDictionary)Tx.GetObject(imageDict, OpenMode.ForWrite);
                    RasterImageDef imageDef = null;
                    foreach (DBDictionaryEntry ImageDef in ImageDic)
                    {
                        imageDef = Tx.GetObject(
                                            ImageDef.Value, OpenMode.ForWrite) as RasterImageDef;
                        if (imageDef == null) continue;
                        IntPtr pointer = imageDef.OpenImage();
                        try
                        {
                            PixelFormat format = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
                            int bitsPerPixel = ((int)format & 0xff00) >> 8;
                            int bytesPerPixel = (bitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
                            int stride = 4 * (((int)imageDef.Size.X * bytesPerPixel + 3) / 4);

                            Bitmap _img = new Bitmap((int)imageDef.Size.X, (int)imageDef.Size.Y, stride, format, pointer);
                            _img.Save("c:\\1.Jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
                            imageDef.CloseImage();
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            imageDef.CloseImage();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've already tried that but without success. If you check the pointer returned by `OpenImage` with the debugger, you will see that it is always equal to zero and I don't know why...

If you unload the image before calling `OpenImage`, you will get an error.

You can try `ImageCopy` instead of `OpenImage` but note that the pointer returned is a pointer to an Atil image, which is an object not exposed in .NET.

I think the only way to do that is to use C++/ObjectARX.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't pay attention to the Atil part.

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this problem? and I'm thinking of writing the functionality that I need in C++, and using a wrapper to call it from C#, would that work ?, thanks.

Comment: > I'm thinking of writing the functionality that I need in C++
Yes but you need to be good at C++ and there is not a lot of documentation or samples for the Atil library. I think you will need to implement a very big wrapper.